# LINQ How retrieve anonymous property

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of integers. I can `GroupBy`, `Sort`, and `Take` the less repeat element:

```
int [] list = new int[] {0, 1, 1, 0, 2};
var result = list
    .GroupBy(a => a)
    .Select(g => new {
        Number = g.Key,
        Total = g.Count()
    })
    .OrderBy(g => g.Total).Take(1);
```

Inside a `foreach` I can retrieve the result, I even have Intellisense for group properties `{Number, Total}`

```
foreach (var group in result)
{
    // Display key and its values.
    Console.WriteLine("Number = {0} Total: {1}", group.Number, group.Total);
}
```

But I don't like to do a `foreach` to do that, I prefer to do something like

```
result.Number or 
result[0].Number
```

But doesn't work. What should be the right way to do it?

Comment: Did you try adding a .ToArray() after the Take(1) call? Or FirstOrDefault. By the way, this happens because LINQ arrays are not evaluated at the time they are created, but only when you iterate through them or use something like ToArray or FirstOrDefault that causes the query to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Take(1)` which still returns an `IEnumerable`. You probably want to use [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) which does not return an IEnumerable.

```
.OrderBy(g => g.Total).Take(1);
```

Then you can use it like `result.Number` and `result.Total`.

Comment: You beat Rahul for 2 seconds. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that [Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns `IEnumerable`, so if you want to fetch only first element, in that case use [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
var result = list.GroupBy(a => a)
                        .Select(g => new
                        {
                            Number = g.Key,
                            Total = g.Count()
                        })
                        .OrderBy(g => g.Total).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then, you can simply say: - `result.Number`. Please note `FirstOrDefault` may return null so better check for nulls before accessing any property otherwise you may get `Null Reference Exception`.

Also, if you are looking for any specific index then you can use [ElementAtOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb494386(v=vs.100).aspx) like this:-

```
var result = list.GroupBy(.....)..OrderBy(g => g.Total);
int SecondNumber = result.result.ElementAtOrDefault(1).Number;
```

But again be aware of `NRE`.

Comment: @Downvotrer, please do comment if I posted anything wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous type does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`, there for you cannot access it via index.

If you only want the very first object you can use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault`. If you cast it to an array, you can use an index and then have support for your properties again:

```
result.FirstOrDefault().Number;
result.ToArray()[1].Number;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check these Methods:

```
.FirstOrDefault(); //gets the first element
.Take(n); //gets the first n elements
.Skip(n).FirstOrDefault(); //gets the (n+1)th element
.Skip(n).Take(m); //gets the first m elements after n elements
```